# Windows 7 backup two external hard drives that I swap weekly

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup

For about a year I have used Windows 7's back-up tool and Mozy to do local and remote back-ups. Now that Mozy is eliminating the unlimited packages, I plan to switch to two external drives that I will swap weekly (one attached to the laptop and one kept offsite, but never more than two weeks out of sync).

Is there a way to do this? I connected the new drive, and it imaged and backed-up just fine. But when I connected the original back-up the Windows 7 back-up tool doesn't recognize it. I found this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/177595/your-home-backup-strategy) on back-up solutions, but didn't see any answers that addressed this question. Sadly I found this question (unanswered) several times on the Windows 7 support site.

I like the simplicity of the Windows 7 backup tool, but I am open to everything. Should I just image and `rsync`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another drive image software or backup utility, the one built into Windows is not very flexible. [I like Easeus Todo 3.5 FREE](http://majorgeeks.com/EASEUS_Todo_Backup_Free_Edition_d6195.html)

.

Comment: This is not really true. The one built into Windows is actually very flexible. It's just that you have to use the command line interface to access most of that flexibility. It's the management GUI part of it that isn't flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Super Flexible file syncronizer is a tool you can use, it can set up different profiles, and can be scheduled and such.

http://www.superflexible.com/

> Back up your data and synchronize PCs, Macs, servers, notebooks, and online storage space.
>
> You can set up as many different jobs as you need and run them manually or using the scheduler. The software works with local hard drives, network drives and any other mounted volumes. In addition, it comes with support for FTP, SSH, HTTP, WebDAV, Amazon S3, and Google Docs. You can use ZIP compression and data encryption. On Windows NT/2000 or higher, the scheduler can run as a service - without users having to log on. There are powerful >synchronization modes, including Standard Copying, Exact Mirror, and SmartTracking.
>
> The latest version features a carefully designed GUI with numerous improvements to make an extremely versatile synchronizing and back-up tool.